# Algorithm to project onto line segments

Tags: computational-geometry

I have the following problem: A large number $N$ of (finite length) line segments in the plane (if it helps, we can assume non-intersecting except at end points, and forming a graph with a small number of components); and a smaller number $n$ of points.  For each point, I wish to find the closest line segment.

Given one line segment, this is easy: orthogonally project onto the line, and if this doesn't fall on the line segment, choose the appropriate end point.  This gives a naive $O(Nn)$ algorithm.

I am wondering if there is a clever data structure which, with some pre-processing on the lines, would give a faster algorithm?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just throw it in a quad tree? (Treat each line as a continuous set of points, stop iterating when any quad has points from only a single line segment.)

Comment: You might also want to search around for "voronoi diagram line segments", though I don't know whether the solutions there will match your use-case.

Comment: I'm wondering if there are data structures for 2D visibility that be useful here.  Or perhaps you can adapt a sweepline algorithm for constructing a Voronoi diagram to handle the case of line segments rather than points.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I'll have a search for quad trees (I had this vague idea they only helped with nearest neighbour like searches; but I'm probably mistaken) and will have another look at voronoi diagrams.

Comment: CGAL can compute voronoi diagrams for line segments: http://doc.cgal.org/Manual/3.1/doc_html/cgal_manual/Segment_Voronoi_diagram_2/Chapter_main.html